# Visual Studio Code (via Anaconda Navigator): from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces

Tags: visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

I open my Visual Studio Code via the Anaconda Navigator and am trying to do the following in my Jupyter notebook.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
```

However, i am getting this error.

```
File \anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:643, in HTTPDefaultErrorHandler.http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 643     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Would really appreciate some help!

Have tried running the code by launching Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Navigator and it works. I just can't get it to work on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and I'm not sure what you need help with. Like, to start, do you understand what the error message is saying? Do you know why you might get a 403 error? Check out [ask] for tips. You can [edit] to clarify. I added the tag of the library you're using, if it helps.

Comment: Just to be clear, IDK why you're getting that error and I haven't used sklearn myself, but off the top of my head, some things I would check are proxy settings and whether VSC is using the same environment as Jupyter